# on loading page, display a PHP file in a div and on clicks display other PHP files in the same div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to display a PHP file on loading the page and display other PHP files in the same div. Here is my code...

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
   <li><a class="ajax-link" href="menu.php">Menu</a></li>
   <li><a class="ajax-link" href="#">History</a></li>
   <li><a class="ajax-link" href="editdetails.php">Details</a></li>
   <li class="last"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul> <!-- end #nav -->

<div class="page" id="main_content">
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
       $("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#main_content").load(this.href);
       });
     });
    </script>
</div>
```

This code is displaying the pages only after clicking but, i want to display the menu page on loading itself. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li><a class="ajax-link" href="menu.php">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a class="ajax-link" href="#">History</a></li>
    <li><a class="ajax-link" href="editdetails.php">Details</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>    
</ul> <!-- end #nav -->

<div class="page" id="main_content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //It will load content once your page get load
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#main_content").load('MENU_LINK');
    });

    //It will load on clicking of links
   $("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#main_content").load(this.href);
   });        
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried your code. It is displaying the menu on loading. But, it is not displaying the PHP pages on clicks.

Comment: can you please tell me what are you getting in alert box? `$("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();alert(this.href);
         $("#main_content").load(this.href);
   });   `

Comment: I just placed your jquery in that div and it worked! :D

Comment: I believe you have removed `$(function() {`, right?

Comment: No, I didn't remove anything from the code, i just placed your script inside the div

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#main_content").load('http://your.link/');
        });        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="">
        <ul id="nav" class="nav">
            <li><a class="ajax-link" href="menu.php">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a class="ajax-link" href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a class="ajax-link" href="editdetails.php">Details</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="page" id="main_content"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help ya :)

Comment: No... Let me be clear first, I need to display menu page on loading the web page in a div. And I want to display every other PHP files in the same div by clicking the links in my navbar